# Classic workspace switcher for Ubuntu-gnome 14.04.2 LTS, want row of 12 workspaces

Tags: gnome, workspaces, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, ubuntu-gnome

With too much baggage on my Ubuntu 12.04, I did a format and new install of Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.2 LTS, an official Ubuntu distro using the Gnome desktop.

The Nvidia drivers for the GPU seem to work nicely now on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.2, whereas when I tried replacing Ubuntu 12.04LTS with Unity, the drivers were problematic. Firefox was impossible without hardware acceleration and failed, locking up constantly before.

However, the dozen workspace buttons in the bottom panel I had before are missing, and instead a tiny menu-like box appears, which I dislike, and find difficult to work with.

I like the row of boxes I can name and drag windows around as I constantly work with multiple windows for my websites, i.e., My websites; Vendors; Sales sites (e.g., Amazon); workspace; My Server; File Manager; My CDN; workspace; SEO; Spreadsheets; Workspace; Gmail; email; and so forth.

I searched for Gnome extensions, including in the "Ubuntu software installer” and Synaptic, among other places, and have not found what I need for this  Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04.2 install.

How might I return to the horizontal layout of multiple individual workspaces in this Gnome?

Comment: That is Gnome 3 on that edition, very different than old Gnome.  You should tru Ubuntu Mate.  Mate is a continuation/fork of Gnome 2.  Should be what fits your desires.  It runs fast too.